# Tailwind css breaks in production with NEXTJS

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, vercel

I am facing issue with Tailwind config in production. Purge breaks all my CSS in production and can't seem to figure out why. All my components are inside `client` folder and also have included the same path in the purge path. Am I missing anything in the config here?

```js
module.exports = {
    purge: ["./pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./client/**/*.{js,jsx,tsx,tsx}"]
};
```

[image]

Comment: It's hard to say what is going wrong with only the information you provided. Could you give more detail about your directory structure?

Comment: hey thanks for looking into this issue here's how i have structured my project [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g22xL.jpg

Comment: Could you show all files that reference class names from tailwind?